# How to connect PyQt5 pyqtSlot to QML ListView signal "activated"?

Tags: python-3.x, listview, qml, pyqt5, qqmlapplicationengine

I would like to connect the `activated` signal from a **QML** `ListView` to a `pyqtSlot` decorated method from my **Python3/PyQt5** (5.6) code.

My current approach is to load the QML scene in my code through `QQmlApplicationEngine` and then use `findChild()` to get a reference to my `ListView`.

The problem is, that I can only find the ListView when searching for a QObject like `findChild(QObject, 'myList')`. But htis object does not give me access to the `activated` signal, most likely because this signal is only defined for `QAbstractItemView` and it descendants.

So if I try `findChild(QListView, 'myList')` the result is `None`. Therefor I'm not able to get to the `activated` signal. Is this a bug in PyQt5 or is there another way for me to connect to this signal?

Here is some minimal working example.

**list.py:**

```
import sys
from OpenGL import GL
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListView
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

# Main Function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create main app
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create QML engine
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine(app)

    # Load the QML scene from file
    engine.load(QUrl('List.qml'))

    for root in engine.rootObjects():
        node = root.findChild(QListView, 'myList')
        if node:
            # At this point I would like to connect something to the
            # node.activated signal
            print(node)

    # Execute the application and exit
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**List.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
  visibility: Window.FullScreen
  visible: true
  ListView {
    objectName: "myList"
    anchors.fill: parent
    delegate: Item {
      width: parent.width * 0.8
      height: 40
      Row {
        id: row1
        Rectangle {
          width: 40
          height: 40
          color: colorCode
        }

        Text {
          text: name
          font.bold: true
          anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        spacing: 10
      }
    }
    model: ListModel {
      ListElement {
        name: "Grey"
        colorCode: "grey"
      }

      ListElement {
        name: "Red"
        colorCode: "red"
      }

      ListElement {
        name: "Blue"
        colorCode: "blue"
      }

      ListElement {
        name: "Green"
        colorCode: "green"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using `QQuickView` instead of `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

I changed your python script to add a new class which inherits from `QQuickView`, and added a signal to the QML object named "myList".

Moreover, into the QML I removed the `Window` type for `Item` type (you can't use `Window` with `QQuickView`). If you want to display your application in full screen, you'll have to specify it into `MyView` class.
In the example, if you click on one of the colored rectangles, the index will be displayed in the console.

list.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListView
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView, QQuickItem

class MyView(QQuickView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Load the QML scene from file
        self.setSource(QUrl('List.qml'))    
        #connect signal and source
        list = self.rootObject().findChild(QQuickItem, 'myList')
        list.mySignal.connect(self.mySlot)

    def mySlot(self, index):
        print(index)

# Main Function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create main app
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create QML view
    view = MyView()
    view.show()    

    # Execute the application and exit
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

List.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {
  width: 500
  height: 500
  ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    id: list
    objectName: "myList"
    signal mySignal(int index)
    delegate: Item {
      width: parent.width * 0.8
      height: 40
      Row {
        id: row1
        Rectangle {
          width: 40
          height: 40
          color: colorCode

          MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: list.mySignal(index)
          }
        }

        Text {
          text: name
          font.bold: true
          anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        spacing: 10
      }
    }
    model: ListModel {
      ListElement {
        name: "Grey"
        colorCode: "grey"
      }

      ListElement {
        name: "Red"
        colorCode: "red"
      }

      ListElement {
        name: "Blue"
        colorCode: "blue"
      }

      ListElement {
        name: "Green"
        colorCode: "green"
      }
    }
  }

}
```